IntellijIDEA не может найти docker.sock
Я столкнулся с проблемой, когда пытался запустить docker compose из под IntellijIDEA, добавил Docker локально в конфигурацию IntellijIDEA.
Но вот проблема.. он не может найти docker.sock
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (Details: [2] No such file or directory)

Хотя я перепроверил, демон докера запущен.

и файл docker.sock имеется

(в группе docker я нахожусь.)

Возможно ваш текущий пользователь системы не имеет доступа.
Можно попробовать:
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)

@Komdosh, я забыл добавить, что я уже это сделал (сразу как только поставил докер)

А IDEA откуда как установлена?

@andreymal flatpak

Вот IDEA и изолирована в своём флатпаковом манямирке и не имеет доступа к внешнему миру с докером

@andreymal как исправить? удалять и устанавливать не из flatpak?

@andreymal сработало! удалил и переустановил ее через ToolBox
